# Is there a way to send alert emails if Kubernetes detects an authentication attempt, even if I don't have access to the master node?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have a Kubernetes cluster in OVH, and I need to send alerts if the API detects an authentication attempt. I know I could use a script to monitor Kubernetes audit log files and send emails if there are authentication attempts. However, the problem is that I don't have access to the master node.

So, I'm wondering if there is a solution for this.

I tried to configure my cluster to write audit logs in workers as well. I attempted to use Prometheus to send authentication alerts, but I couldn't find the right metrics to use.

Thank you.